# Each finite field has a primitive element

Tags: finite-fields

I'm reading David R. Finston and Patrick J. Morandi's book [Abstract Algebra: Structure and Application](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319044974) and in section 7.2 page 109 it mentions

> It’s true that every finite field has a primitive element. However, the
>   proof of this fact involves more complicated ideas that we will
>   consider, so we do not give the proof.

I understand some proof might be hard, based on more complex concepts, but leaving this dangling it’s a bit itchy .. May I ask where can I find a relative simple proof?

Comment: You need to know that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, which involves combining the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups, with the fact that a polynomial of degree $k$ with coefficients in a field has at most $k$ roots.

Comment: If "primitive element" means generator of its multiplicative group, then https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59903/96384.

Comment: On the other hand, if primitive element means an element $\alpha\in F$ such that $F=\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ then this might be easier to show. This of course depends a lot on the context.

Comment: This is not the general case, but here's a good exposition of [seven proofs](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf) that $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\times}$ is cyclic.

Comment: Most likely it relies on the fact that if $F$ is a finite field, there is at most one subgroup of given size, and as a consequence, in $F^*$, there are at most $\phi(d)$ elements with order $d$. It follows from this, Lagrange’s theorem, and $\sum_{d|n}{\phi(d)}=n$ that any subgroup of order $n$ of $F^*$ must have one element of order $n$ so is cyclic. In particular, $F^*$ is a cyclic group: if $\alpha$ is its generator, $\alpha$ is primitive.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic

Comment: I rather like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/837571/403337. This uses precisely what @Arturo mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an elementary proof, in the sense that it avoids the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

The proof is based on the following elementary statement:

Let $F$ be a finite field and $a$ an element of order $m$ and $b$ an element of order $n$. Then $F$ contains an element $c$ of order $lcm(m,n)$.

Let's begin the proof. Let $a$ be an element of maximal order, say $n$. To obtain a contradiction, we assume that $n<|F|-1$. Then we can pick an element $b\notin \langle a \rangle\cup \{0\}$. Denote the order of $b$ with $m$. By maximality of $n$, we know $m\leq n$. If $m$ divides $n$, then the polynomial $X^n-1$ has strictly more than $n$ roots ($b$ and the elements of $\langle a\rangle$). Thus we must have that $m$ does not divide $n$. But then $lcm(m,n)>n$ and the statement above gives an element with order $lcm(m,n)$, contradicting maximality of $n$.

This shows that $n=|F|-1$ and thus $a$ is a primitive element, i.e. a generator for the multiplicative group.

Comment: What is the proof of the "elementary statement"?  It's easy to see that $o(ab) \leq \operatorname{lcm}(m, n)$.  But equality isn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @RobertShore: See, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215438/how-do-i-prove-that-there-exists-a-cyclic-subgroup-of-order-lcm-of-orders-of-cyc)